# Window.onload function does not work in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onload

We've made a script with a function and I am trying to call it with window.onload. The purpose of the script is to fill a canvas with a couple of images right as the page loads. This works in Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari, but not in Google Chrome. We've tried googling for the issue but haven't found one yet so we hoped anyone of you would be ablpe to help us?!

This is the HTML and the Javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Opdracht 2</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/canvasopdracht2.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <img id="logo" height='100px'><br> -->
    <canvas id='canvas2' width='1900' height='1000'>
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

</body>
    <script src="js/addlistener.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script> <!-- EaselJS inladen -->
    <script src="js/canvasopdracht2.js"></script>
</html>
```

//JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = time2paint;

var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas2");
var canvasPositionsX=[]; //array
var canvasPositionsY=[]; //array
var canvasPositions=[]; //array
var genPositionX=-50; var genPositionY=-50;
var Position = 0;
var usedPositions = []; //array
var finalPositions;
var randomPosition = [];
var singlePosition = [];

var SplitRandomUsedPosition;
var randomUsedPosition;

var attachedPositionX1;
var attachedPositionX2;
var attachedPositionY1;
var attachedPositionY2;
var attachedPositions=[];

function time2paint(event){
  var canvasWidth = 1900; var canvasHeight = 1000;
  var statistics = 10;

  //generate x positions
  for(s=1; s<=(canvasWidth/50); s++){
    genPositionX=genPositionX + 50;
    canvasPositionsX.push(genPositionX);
  }
  //generate y positions
  for(s=1; s<=(canvasHeight/50); s++){
    genPositionY=genPositionY + 50;
    canvasPositionsY.push(genPositionY);
  }
  //generate a grid (array)
  //combine generated y and x positions, and put them all in the canvasPositions array together
  //voor elke x coordinate worden alle y coordinaten toegevoegd in een 2e for loop
  for(i=0; i<canvasPositionsX.length; i++){
    for(s=0; s<canvasPositionsY.length; s++){
      Position = canvasPositionsX[i] + " " + canvasPositionsY[s];
      canvasPositions.push(Position);
    } 
  }
   //get coordinates relative to client window
  var inx = event.clientX; 
  var iny = event.clientY; 
  //get offset of the element, relative to client window
  var minx = getOffset( document.getElementById('canvas2') ).left; 
  var miny = getOffset( document.getElementById('canvas2') ).top; 

    for(i=1; i<=statistics; i++){
      //get final coordinates, relative to element window
      var x = inx - minx;
      var y = iny - miny;

      //create image (50x50 afbeelding)
      var image = new createjs.Bitmap("images/plaatje (" + i + ").jpg");
      image.scaleX=0.25; //50px
      image.scaleY=0.25; //50px

      //als image 1 .. 
      if(i == 1){
        //get center 
        image.x = canvasWidth / 2; 
        image.y = canvasHeight / 2;
        //push first image coordinates in usedpositions
        usedPositions.push(image.x + " " + image.y);
      //als andere image .. 
      }else{
        //get random usedposition
        randomUsedPosition = usedPositions[Math.floor(Math.random() * usedPositions.length)];
        SplitRandomUsedPosition = randomUsedPosition.split(" "); // split by space - [0] is x - [1] is y

        //voeg 50px x OF 50px y toe (+ bij elkaar voegen)
        attachedPositionX1 = (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + 50) + " " + parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]);
        attachedPositionX2 = (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) - 50) + " " + parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]);
        attachedPositionY1 = parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + " " + (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]) + 50);
        attachedPositionY2 = parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + " " + (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]) - 50);
        attachedPositions = [attachedPositionX1, attachedPositionX2, attachedPositionY1, attachedPositionY2];
        //random choose where to attach
        randomPosition = attachedPositions[Math.floor((Math.random() * attachedPositions.length))];

        //if random position al wordt gebruikt get nieuwe random coordinates from canvaspositions array
        while(usedPositions.indexOf(randomPosition) > -1){
        randomUsedPosition = usedPositions[Math.floor(Math.random() * usedPositions.length)];
        SplitRandomUsedPosition = randomUsedPosition.split(" "); // split by space - [0] is x - [1] is y

        //voeg 50px x OF 50px y toe (+ bij elkaar voegen)
        attachedPositionX1 = (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + 50) + " " + parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]);
        attachedPositionX2 = (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) - 50) + " " + parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]);
        attachedPositionY1 = parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + " " + (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]) + 50);
        attachedPositionY2 = parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[0]) + " " + (parseInt(SplitRandomUsedPosition[1]) - 50);
        attachedPositions = [attachedPositionX1, attachedPositionX2, attachedPositionY1, attachedPositionY2];
        //random choose where to attach
        randomPosition = attachedPositions[Math.floor((Math.random() * attachedPositions.length))];
         }

        //push chosen position in usedPositions array and save final image positions
        usedPositions.push(randomPosition);
        finalPositions = randomPosition.split(" "); 

        //draw image
        image.x = finalPositions[0]; 
        image.y = finalPositions[1]; 
      }

   //add fade-in jquery effects

        stage.addChild(image);
        stage.update(); //update draws to the canvas
    }  

        console.log(usedPositions);  
}

function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: Put the script tags *inside* the body or head.

Comment: And use an event listener, the standard and well-regarded way: `window.addEventListener('load', time2paint, false)`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @somethinghere - We just added that event listener, and also tried putting the script tag inside the body, as suggested by Alex K. However, this didn't fix loading the canvas images within chrome.

Comment: Nope, that did not work unfortunately @somethinghere

Comment: What does your console say? It must be reporting an error.

Comment: That would 've helped a lot, but it doesn't. Loading the canvas properly works in firefox, safari, and internet explorer, but not in chrome, and it doesn't give me an error within the console.  It does show me the console.log(usedPositions), like this:  ["950 500", "950 450", "900 450", "950 550", "950 400", "950 350", "900 350", "850 450", "900 500", "1000 400"] - However, when i copy the ''localhost/file.html'' into the browser adress bar, it does actually work. Then when i try to refresh, it shows a blank page again. Any ideas? @somethinghere

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know, I dont use Stage.js. Sorry mate, I dont see anything wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps try a simpler example with the onload, to determine if it is related to that, or the rest of the code.